# Adding overflow hidden to body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a popup and I want to add overflow hidden to the body once the popup is displayed and when it is hidden I was to change it back to scroll. The popup is being inserted via a 3rd party plugin and the only javascript file I have access to is my theme one. I've currently got this

```
$( "div" ).click(function() {
  if ($('body').css('overflow-y') == "hidden") {
      $("body").css("overflow-y", "scroll"); 
  }
});

$("#inline").click(function() {
  $("body").css("overflow-y", "hidden");
});
```

I've just used the global `div` to hide it since the plugin is being added in last. If i used only the second function it adds hidden to the body as needed but if I include the first function it overrides the second function and just allows scrolling all the time. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Which 3rd party plugin are you using? Typically the plugin to show popup / modal dialog will have some events raised. Check if you can handle events like popup shown / popup closed etc.

Answer (score 0):

It would be because your element with `id inline` is nested inside a div. You need to stop click event from propogating to the parent of this element using `e.stopPropogation();`

Use

```
$( "div" ).click(function() {
  if ($('body').css('overflow-y') == "hidden") {
      $("body").css("overflow-y", "scroll"); 
  }
});
$("#inline").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropogation();
  $("body").css("overflow-y", "hidden");
});
```